# Cardinality the set of strictly decreasing functions $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'd like some help/clues with finding the cardinality of the set of the strictly decreasing functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.

I'm not quite sure if it's countable. Hints or clues will be helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: I dk why Martini's A is deleted. It's perfect.  Any non-empty collection of natural numbers has a least member . If $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ were strictly decreasing then  $\{f(n): n\in \mathbb N\}$ would be non-empty and have no least member.

Answer (score 8):

It's zero. There are no strictly decreasing functions $f \colon \mathbf N \to \mathbf N$. Note that for any $n \in \mathbf N$, such an $f$ would have 
$$ f(0) > \cdots > f(n) $$
hence $f(n) \le f(0) - n$. Now let $n = f(0)+1$, this would give 
$$ f\bigl(f(0) + 1\bigr) \le f(0) - f(0) - 1 = -1. $$
Contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not many *strictly decreasing* maps $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ out there, because a strictly decreasing map $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z$ satisfies $f(n)\le f(0)-n$

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a strictly decreasing function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Thus, the cardinality is $0$.

Now, if you change "strictly decreasing" to "non-increasing" then the set of such functions is countably infinite. To prove it, here's an outline:

$(1)\;$A non-increasing function from N to N must be eventually constant.

$(2)\;$There are a countably infinite number of possibilities for the eventual constant value.

$(3)\;$Fix an eventual constant value, $c$ say. For a given non-increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with eventual constant value $c$, define the length of $f$ to be the number of terms in the sequence $f(1),f(2),f(3), ...$ which exceed $c$.

$(4)\;$For each $c$ and each length $n$, there are at most countably many non-increasing functions with eventual constant value $c$ and length $n$.

$(5)\;$Finish by noting that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: +1. An intuitive comment for the OP: one way to convince yourself that a set is probably countable is to figure out that its elements can be described by "finitely much" information. So, how would you describe a non-increasing map $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$? Well, you could tell me $f$'s values up until the point where it "gets constant" (there's finitely many of these), and then say "now it doesn't change ever again". That's a finite description, and tells you everything there is to know about $f$! So that suggests that your set is countable, which quasi's answer rigorously proves.

Answer (score 0):

If such sequence exist then :

$\forall n\in \Bbb N \; f(n)\geq 0$

and $f$ strictly decreasing, thus

$\lim_{n\to + \infty}f(n)$ exists $=L$.

so

$f(\Bbb N)=[f(0),L)\cap \Bbb N$ or$[f(0),L]\cap \Bbb N$ which is finite
. This means that the sequence $f(n)$ is stationnary from a certain $n_0$, and this is in contradiction with $f$ is strictly decreasing.

$f$ couldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

martini's answer is correct. You can think of it as a "corollary" to what you should have truly learned from this exercise:

**Proposition.**
Let $ f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} $.
There exists a natural number $ n $ such that $ f\left(n\right)\le f\left(n+1\right) $.

*Proof.*
Let $ u $ be the least element of $ \operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $.
Therefore for each $ v\in\operatorname{ran}\left(f\right)\setminus\left\{u\right\} $, $ u<v $.
Because $ u\in\operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $, there exists $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ f\left(n\right)=u $.
Because $ n+1\in\mathbb{N} $, $ f\left(n+1\right)\in\operatorname{ran}\left(f\right) $.
Therefore if $ f\left(n+1\right)\ne f\left(n\right) $, then $ f\left(n\right)<f\left(n+1\right) $.
Therefore $ f\left(n\right)\le f\left(n+1\right) $.